# Почему простой Perl FastCGI скрипт не создает сокет

Tags: fastcgi, perl

Добро всем!

Решил изучить FastCGI , на CPAN-e есть модуль FCGI, который реализует этот протокол.

Тал вот беру пример из документации

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use FCGI;

my $count = 0;
my $request = FCGI::Request();

while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n", ++$count);
}
```

далее запускаю скрипт в терминале и вместо того чтобы откыть сокетскрипт просто печатает 
то что в принте.

а по идее вроде бы я должен был получить бесконечный цыкл.

пробовал еще в этом варианте

```
use FCGI;

my $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket(":8080", 5);

my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, );

my $count = 0;

while($request->Accept() >= 0 ) {
     print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
     print "fcgi works $count\n";
     $count++;

}
```

результат тот же, что же я делаю не так?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант и не должен работать в "автономном" скрипте, читаем документацию по поводу аргументов FCGI::Request()

> socket (default: 0)
> ...
>
> ```
> You should only use your own socket if your program is not started by a process manager such as mod_fastcgi
> ```

Со втором не знаю что, попробуйте вывести $!. Может порт занят (уж очень 8080 популярен), а может запускаете под Windows - как оно там живёт даже гадать не хочется...

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Вывел $!, оказалось просто забыл передать сам сокет запросу, то есть написал

my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, );

а надо бы 

my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $socket);